# Google Authentication ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, google-oauth

I have some problem while google redirects to a callback method it throws [Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0af0.png)

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Conte>(config =>
            config.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Identity")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Conte>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie("Cook")
                .AddGoogle(config =>
                {
                    config.SignInScheme = "Cook";
                    config.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:Client_Id"];
                    config.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:Client_Secret"];

                    config.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "UserId");
                    config.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "EmailAddress", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
                    config.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name");

                });

                    services.AddMvc();
    }
```

AccountController.cs

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/google-login")]
    public async Task LoginGoogle()
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Google", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/signin-google" });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/signin-google")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {   
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

It go to 
[Google Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5mFd.png)

And when I tying to authorize i throws an exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) from MS:

> The Google authentication configured later in this tutorial will **automatically** handle requests at /signin-google route to implement the OAuth flow.

The /signin-google route is handled by the middleware, not by your MVC controller. Your external login should route to something like /ExternalLoginCallback

Comment: It really was one of the problem. Thanks, but anyway _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); returns always null.

Comment: Hard to say anything without additional info. Try to examine your traffic using dev console. Try to call and see HttpContext?.Request?.Cookies?.Select(x => $"{x.Key}:{x.Value};"); directly.